# Is there's a way of importing files I serve through express.static?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, import

### Background:

I have a folder of SVG's which is being served by the server-side with `express.static('public)`.

Inside my component, I want to: `import SVG from '/public/assets/${filename}.svg'`.

The `filename` is a props being passed into the component.

### Problem

I need to do something like this:

***Pseudo code!:***

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
   import MySvg from '/public/assets/${props.filename}.svg';  //This is not working

   return(
      <MySvg />
   );
}
```

### Questions:

When I use an image from the static files I refer to it like this:

`<img src="/public/assets/myImg.jpeg" />`.

1. Is it possible to import static files like this? 
   `import myImg from '/public/assets/mySvg.svg'`?
2. How can I ***lazy import*** the SVG file, when I need to use some props value
   in order to create the path to the SVG file?